# Magento 2 Delete Item confirm Popup

Tags: magento2.2

In my custom theme,

i cannot get mini cart and checkout cart delete confirm popup can anyone help how to get it in custom theme.

Comment: please share code  related with  delete confirm pop

Comment: The theme is new so what type of code you are talking about.

Comment: I just say when i enable my theme delete product confirm popup not showing

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 handles this using Js Files
Check Magento Checkout Module - Please note if you have overridden this module and files then check in that particular module

You Can override this files if you u want to modify any content in the popup:
Minicart Popup : 
/web/js/sidebar.js
/web/js/view/minicart.js

Classic Checkout Doesn't have any popup by default.
You need to check in the theme or any customer module which you have installed